# ¿como importar clases de otra carpeta?

Tags: java

intente crear un código en java por medio del block de notas en el cual abriera otros proyectos que tengo, por lo que los tengo que tener en carpetas para poder diferenciar cada uno y sus respectivas imágenes, pero no se como abrir ahora esos documentos desde mi programa principal ¿alguna respuesta?

pd: soy algo nuevo en esto asi que puedo tener muchos errores o tener algo completamente mal

```
import PAlexis.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Buscador extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private final JButton boton;
    private String texto = "";
    private final JComboBox proyecto;
    private final JLabel titulo;
    private final JMenuBar menus;
    private final JMenu cerrar, opciones;

 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
        if (boton == evento.getSource()) {
            texto = proyecto.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (texto.equals("")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debes elegir algo para empezar a buscar buscar");
            } else {
                if (texto.equals("base de Informacion del trabajador de GAMESA")) {
                    Inicio bi = new Inicio();
                    bi.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
                    bi.setVisible(true);
                    this.setVisible(false);
                }
                if (texto.equals("Finiquito de la empresa de NISSAN")) {
                   Bienvenida ventanabienvenida = new Bienvenida();
                   ventanabienvenida.setBounds(0,0,350,450);
                   ventanabienvenida.setVisible(true);
                   ventanabienvenida.setResizable(false);
                   ventanabienvenida.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Buscador ventana = new Buscador();
        ventana.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 700);
        ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ventana.setResizable(false);
        ventana.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En principio te recomendaría agregar el ActionListener a JComboBox para que pueda detectar cuándo el usuario selecciona un elemento de la lista.
Luego usa el elemento seleccionado para crear un objeto de archivo y luego usa este objeto para abrir el archivo de proyecto, así:

```
JComboBox projectComboBox = new JComboBox();
projectComboBox.addItem("Proyecto ejemplo 1");
projectComboBox.addItem("Proyecto ejemplo 2");

// Agrego el ActionListener al JComboBox 
projectComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // obtengo el item seleccionado
    String selectedProject = (String) projectComboBox.getSelectedItem();

    // creo un objeto File con la opcion elegida
    File selectedFile = new File(selectedProject);

    // Abrir el proyecto seleccionado

    if (file.exists()) {
      // si el File existe...
    } else {
      // sino...
    }

  }

});
```